# Is there a way to tell a file type (executable, text, etc.) in Go?

Tags: go

It there a built-in way to get a file type in Go?

Is it sufficient to guess from the filename alone (in Windows) or is there a way to tell only basically if the file is, say, an executable file? I'd like to find a cross-platform method of doing this, and reading a filename and working from that may miss executable files that are renamed to *.jpg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use MIME type guessing using [mime.TypeByExtension](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/#TypeByExtension) or [http.DetectContentType](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DetectContentType) from the standard library or use third-party `libmagic` bindings, e.g. [magicmime](https://github.com/rakyll/magicmime).